# Rails, Nginx and PostgreSQL - 502 Gateway Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, nginx, passenger

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 on Linode and I'm trying to get Rails 3.1, Nginx 1.0.6, Passenger 3.0.9 and PostgreSQL 8.4 set-up and running.  I've managed to deploy my application and it all appears to work perfectly but after a few successful HTTP requests the server begins to return 502 Gateway Errors.

I've looked in the Nginx log and it seems to be a PostgreSQL problem, I use the same set-up on my OS X development machine (PostgreSQL 8.4, Rails 3.1 and WEBrick) and it works perfectly.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

---

```
2011/09/26 11:43:41 [error] 19694#0: *152 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: <REDACTED>, server: localhost, request: "GET /news/new HTTP/1.0", upstream: "passenger:unix:/passenger_helper_server:", host: "<REDACTED>"
[ pid=19978 thr=-609427238 file=utils.rb:176 time=2011-09-26 11:43:41.504 ]: *** Exception PGError in application (server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.**
) (process 19978, thread #<Thread:0xb759c1b4>):
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:276:in `query'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:276:in `clear_cache!'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:275:in `each_value'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:275:in `clear_cache!'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:303:in `disconnect!'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:202:in `disconnect_without_synchronization!'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:201:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:201:in `disconnect_without_synchronization!'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/synchronization.rb:35:in `disconnect!'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/synchronization.rb:34:in `disconnect!'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:395:in `clear_all_connections!'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:395:in `each_value'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:395:in `clear_all_connections!'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123:in `__send__'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123:in `clear_all_connections!'
        from /opt/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:398:in `before_handling_requests'
        from /opt/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:204:in `start_request_handler'
        from /opt/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:170:in `send'
        from /opt/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:170:in `handle_spawn_application'
        from /opt/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:479:in `safe_fork'
        from /opt/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:165:in `handle_spawn_application'
        from /opt/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
        from /opt/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
        from /opt/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
        from /opt/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
        from /opt/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:128:in `start'
        from /opt/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `spawn_rack_application'
        from /opt/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
        from /opt/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `spawn_rack_application'
        from /opt/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `synchronize'
        from /opt/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
        from /opt/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'
        from /opt/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'
        from /opt/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
        from /opt/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
        from /opt/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
        from /opt/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
        from /opt/passenger-3.0.9/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99

----------
```

Thanks!

Comment: I seem to have fixed the issue by changing  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false in config/environments/production.rb, I still can't figure out why caching would cause a Postgres error and it's not really a viable option to leave caching off in production mode.

Answer (score 1):

What write to logs PostgreSQL in this case? There must be some reasons to close connection - maybe old version of PostgreSQL?

Comment: I've checked the logs and the only error I can see is: 

2011-09-25 16:43:50 BST LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2011-09-25 18:31:53 BST LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
2011-09-26 11:39:10 BST LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
2011-09-26 11:39:26 BST LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
2011-09-26 13:00:42 BST LOG:  incomplete startup packet.

I'm not entirely sure why the database client e.g. Rails in this case would not send the full data stream, could it perhaps be something to do with the timeout settings for Nginx?

Comment: I'm sorry for too late answer... Which version of Postgresql you have and which version is Postgresql client library?